# Nested array won't render in Vue3 template

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

I am assigning a nested array from an `axios.get` `response` to `state.articles`:

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue";

const state = reactive({
    locale: sessionStorage.locale,
    articles: []
})

axios.get('/blog-index')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data
        for (const [, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
            state.articles.push([
                value['id'],
                value['heading_' + state.locale],
                value['descr_' + state.locale],
                value['content_' + state.locale]
            ]);
        }
        console.log(state.articles[0][0])
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.response);
    });
</script>
```

from this, `console.log(state.articles[0][0])` outputs `6` which is the correct `id`.

However, when I want to render the `id` in my component:

```
<h2>{{ state.articles[0][0] }}</h2>
```

it throws several errors:

[image]

Why is `state.articles[0][0]` `undefined` and why does it work in my component's `script` element but not in the `template`?

`state.articles[0]` renders the correct array in the `template`:

```
[
  6,
  "Newest Article",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda ullam velit voluptatem.",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda ullam velit voluptatem. Aliquid amet consectetur corporis dignissimos, dolorum earum eligendi error esse eum ipsam modi molestias pariatur quasi qui quis repudiandae sint ullam voluptatum? Animi dolorem molestiae reprehenderit ullam voluptates."
]
```

Shouldn't its `0` element be `6`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first rendering that nested values are not available, you should add a condition to check their availability :

```html
<h2 v-if="state.articles[0].length">{{ state.articles[0][0] }}</h2>
```

Comment: I had to do `v-if="state.articles[0]"` to get it to work. Thank you